# Is it necesary to purchase two Datacenter licences if your virtualization infrastructure includes two physical servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, datacenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

We are looking to set up a virtualization environment.  As I assume is standard this will include more than one physical server to run the virtual machines.   As I also think is standard (I could be wrong, please correct me if I'm wrong) the servers will be in a master/failover type arrangement.  Meaning the virtual machines will run on one, and if the server should fail the virtual machines are switched to the other.

My question is, do I need to purchase two data center licences for Windows Server (probably 2008 r2) to run this arrangement?

Comment: Datacenter licenses of what? Windows Server? System Center? SQL Server?

Comment: Windows server 2008.  Apologies I forgot to clarify that.  I did use it as a tag though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your second machine will stay off, then you will only need one license per processor on your server. If your machine will be on, even if only in standby, then you will need one license per processor.

But, if you are going to have two machines, why not use them to load balance your virtual machines?  You may run your machines like half and half, give your servers some relief and, if one fails, you just have to migrate half of your machines.

Comment: TomTom I marked it as correct because I wanted to move on from this question and pick an answer other than yours. you are being rude and snotty.  Disclaimer: I am of course refering to comments TomTom made which he has since edited out.

Comment: Whatever dude..  Hover over the little pencil. It shows "This comment was edited".  You edited out a comment where you called me 'too stupid'.  Anyway I have better things to do than argue with a rude unhelpful person on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your licensing. SOME allows standby nodes to be run without licenses AS PURE STANDBY. Thas means you  ARE allowed to run things on them like controlling, patching, obviously - just no production applications.

Here is the hint: In school you should have learned reading. The license you have is something you can read. I have no idea under what license you operate - for example, if you rent out virtual machines, then the license you purchased is void anyway (as you need spla) so the terms are irrelevant.

Read your license.

Comment: I need to know what/how many licences to get, not what any current licence I own says.

Comment: I DO NOT HAVE A LICENCE to read!  I am not asking if I need to get 'another' licence.  I am asking if I need to buy two licences.  I don't have one licence yet!  We don't have the virtual hardware yet.  I am in the research phase.